# Efficiently gather a list of objects

Tags: c#, list

```
List<MyClass> options = new List<MyClass>();
foreach (MyClass entity in ExistingList) {
    if (entity.IsCoolEnough) {
        options.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

I'm simply curious what the fastest, most efficient way of doing this is. The list isn't very large, but it's run frequently, so I'd like to keep it snappy. I'm not looking for a change in verbosity either. I just want runtime as fast as possible.

Comment: How large is 'Not very large' and how often is 'frequently'? If its a very small list, run every second, it won't matter if you try to optimize it. On the other hand if it's every few milis, and a few thousand items, it's another story.

Comment: Assuming that `ExistingList` is frequently changing, it might be worthwhile to consider doing the selection based on `IsCoolEnough` already during the construction of `ExistingList`. Thereby, this extra selection routine wouldn't be necessary at all. The most efficient code is the one that never runs ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, using LINQ it reads more intuitively:

```
var options = (from e in ExistingList where e.IsCoolEnough select e).ToList();
```

I'm not sure whether it is faster or more efficient, though.

I'd say that for small lists, this is actually some kind of over-optimization, as for short lists, `foreach`, `for` and the above approach shouldn't make a difference at all. So instead of optimizing this, first check whether it imposes a runtime-problem at all.

Comment: This is a great example -- and the advice is solid too. I was trying to be preemptive and avoid a slowdown to start, but waiting to see if it's actually an issue is probably best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible cases of "general" optimization, either at db-level or model-level depending on where the resource hog is.

If you can select via a where on `IsCoolEnough` in db-level:

```
var result = ExistingList.Where(e => e.IsCoolEnough) // still in db?
                         .ToList(); // enumerate
```

If you can't and the expensive operation is `IsCoolEnough`:

```
var result = new ConcurrentBag<MyClass>(); // Thread safe but unordered.
Parallel.ForEach(ExistingList, current =>
             {
               if (current.IsCoolEnough) result.Add(current);
             });
```

It's impossible for me to give more solid advice given the quite unknown requirements. But you do not have any general "faults" in your implementation.

[I like referring to this article, so I'm doing that again now. It's worth the read (Ie click somewhere on/in this line/sentence, it's a link).](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)